# How can I enable a Junit 5 test based on the "OR" of multiple conditions

Tags: junit, junit5

From [JUnit5: Conditional Test Execution](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution):

> When multiple `ExecutionCondition` extensions are registered, a
> container or test is disabled as soon as one of the conditions returns
> disabled.

Given this, I haven't been able to figure out how to enable a test on the "OR" of multiple conditions, such as for example "enable if Condition_A OR Condition_B.  The problem is that as soon as the first condition disables the test, there's no way to re-enable the test based on the second condition.  So, how can I enable a Junit 5 test based on the "OR" of multiple conditions?

Before anyone suggest using a script based condition (`@EnabledIf` or `@DisabledIf`), script based conditions were deprecated in JUnit 5.5 and removed in JUnit 5.6.  Since we're using JUnit 5.7.2, script based conditions aren't available to us.

Answer (score 2):

Custom method-based conditions returned in Jupiter 5.7

> A container or test may be enabled or disabled based on the boolean return of a method via the `@EnabledIf` and `@DisabledIf` annotations. The method is provided to the annotation via its name.

Find details at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution-custom